# How Can I Create a Recursive Python Script to Sort Files and Folders?

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, scripting

So I made this script to sort a folder into subfolders of different types and it worked! But now I would like it to sort folders within the folder I tell it to sort. I tried recursion but it didn't work? is my syntax wrong? Also how would you get it to move file types of x up a directory into the appropriately sorted folder in the folder I told the script to sort? If that makes sense.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/python
import os
path = raw_input("Enter your folder you would like sorted: ")
def searchFolders(path):
    if os.path.exists(path): 
        dirList = os.listdir(path) 
        for filename in dirList: 
            if  ".jpg" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Photos"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Photos")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Photos/" + filename)
            elif ".pptx" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Powerpoints"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Powerpoints")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Powerpoints/" + filename)
            elif ".zip" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Zip Files"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Zip Files")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Zip Files/" + filename)
            elif ".dmg" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Disk Images"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Disk Images")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Disk Images/" + filename)
            elif ".mp3" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Music"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Music")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Music/" + filename)
            elif ".pdf" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Pdf"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Pdf")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Pdf/" + filename)
            elif ".cpp" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "C++"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "C++")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "C++/" + filename)
            elif ".psd" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Photoshop"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Photoshop")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Photoshop/" + filename)
            elif ".dng" in filename:
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Photos/Raw Photos"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Photos/Raw Photos")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Photos/Raw Photos/" + filename)
            elif not "." in filename:
                folderPath = path + filename
                searchFolders(folderPath)   
            else: 
                if not os.path.exists(path + "Random"):
                    os.makedirs(path + "Random")
                os.rename(path + filename, path + "Random/" + filename)

        print "Sorting Complete"
    else:
        print "Folder Does not exist"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shutil.copytree(src,dst)
shutil.rmtree(src)
```

should get you where you want ...

Comment: would I call this at the end of my program or at the beginning?